# How can I speed up this query that joins a table on itself?

Tags: mysql

We have a  `users' table that holds information about our users. One of the fields within this table is called 'query'. I am trying to SELECT the user id's of all users that have the same query.  So my output should look like this:

```
user1_id    user2_id    common_query
   43          2            "foo"
   117         433          "bar"
   1           119          "baz"
   1           52           "qux"
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this query to finish in under an hour (the users table is pretty big). This is my current query:

```
SELECT u1.id,
       u2.id,
       u1.query
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
        ON u1.query = u2.query
       AND u1.id <> u2.id
```

My explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                             | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u1    | index | index_users_on_query | index_users_on_query | 768     | NULL                            | 10905267 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | ref   | index_users_on_query | index_users_on_query | 768     | u1.query                        |       11 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+
```

As you can see from the explain, the users table is indexed on query and the index appears to be being used in my SELECT. I'm wondering why the 'rows' column on table u2 has a value of 11, and not 1. Is there anything I can do to speed this query up? Is my '<>' comparison within the join bad practice?  Also, the id field is the primary key

Comment: Can you post 'show create users'?

Comment: Is there something in particular you are curious about? I'd rather not post the entire schema for my table since it is work-related

Comment: Probably not a big performance difference, but you should probably change `u1.id <> u2.id` to `u1.id < u2.id` to prevent repeating each pair with its opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My biggest concern is the `key_len`, which indicates that MySQL must compare up to 768 bytes in order to lookup each index entry.

For this query, a hash index on `query` could be much more performant (as it would involve substantially shorter comparisons, at the cost of calculating hashes and being unable to sort records using that index):

```sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX (query) USING HASH
```

You might also consider making this a composite on `(query, id)` so that MySQL need not scan into the record itself to test the `<>` criterion.

Comment: @eggyal I will test both of your recommendations (others have suggested the composite key but your reasoning behind it is what I've been looking for). FWIW, the key_len remained at 768 despite explicitly stating 'USING HASH'

Comment: @DukeSilver: Are you sure that the optimiser selected the new hash index and wasn't still choosing the old btree one?  You can use an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html), if necessary.

Comment: @eggyal yes I made sure to delete the old index first.

Answer (score 1):

The main driver of the query is the equality on the `query` field--if it's indexed.  The <> to the `id` is probably not very specific and it shows by the type of select being used for it is  'ref'

Below only applies if 'query' is not indexed....

If `id` is the primary key you could just do this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_1  ON users (query);
```

The result of adding such an index will be a covering index for the query and will result in the fastest execution for the query.

Comment: @DukeSilver see my edit, I added a change for when id is the PK

Comment: @DukeSilver Then this is as optimal as you're going to get.  Sorry, I'm less good at reading explains then create statements.

Answer (score 0):

How many queries do you have? You can add table UsersInQueries:

```
id   queryId   userId
0      5         453   
1      23        732 
2      15        761
```

then select from this table and group by queryId

Answer (score 0):

If you only have up to two users per query, you could do this instead:

```
select query, min(id) as FirstID, max(id) as SecondId
from users
group by query
having count(*) > 1
```

If you have more than two users with the same query, can you explain why you would want all pairs of such users?